# Why does this conditional cause a seg fault?

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

What is the reason for this? I thought that if a pointer is null then the rest of the condition won't be evaluated.

```
// doesn't work:
char *ptr = somefunction();

if (ptr && ptr[0] == '1' || ptr[0] == 't')
  // ...



// does work:
char *ptr = somefunction();
if (ptr)
    if (ptr[0] == '1' || ptr[0] == 't')
        // ...
```

Comment: Not your problem here, but note that just because a pointer is non-null doesn't mean it's valid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ptr && ptr[0] == '1' || ptr[0] == 't'
```

means:

- if `ptr && ptr[0] == '1'` (false, because `ptr` is null and `ptr[0] == '1'` doesn't get evaluated)
- or `ptr[0] == 't'` (boom)

Use:

```
ptr && (ptr[0] == '1' || ptr[0] == 't')
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` has [higher precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) than `||` so the code is equivalent to:

```
if ((ptr && ptr[0] == '1') || ptr[0] == 't')
```

and if the first `(...&&..)` fails, then the second half of `||` is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Your order of evaluation is incorrect. This will work:

```
if (ptr && (ptr[0] == '1' || ptr[0] == 't'))
```

Basically, any time you have both `&&` and `||` in your code, you need a parentheses in there to ensure it does what you mean it to.

Answer (score 1):

You have Null ptr && dereferenced Null ptr which causes seg fault.

C gives you the option to have statements like if (ptr == NULL) do something;
If it always evaluated a condition to false when a null pointer was detected statements like this wouldn't work.